# Best way to add a formatted localized string to an ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, resources, localization, internationalization

I've been using `<asp:Literal runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Blah" />` with resx files in the App_LocalResources directory for translatable strings, but if my key, `Blah.Text` is "Enter the {0} category", how would I pass the parameter to replace {0} in this context?

I know I could use `<%=string.Format(...` but that seems unclean and I can't access the Local Resources in that way. What should I do for this use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of markup:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Blah" />
```

from the code behind:

```
Blah.Text = string.Format(
    "Enter the {0} category", 
    GetLocalResourceObject("Blah").ToString()
);
```

by using [GetLocalResourceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153597.aspx) method.

Comment: If you want to keep your declarative style, create a derived version of the Literal control and add 2 properties to it - FormatString and Value.  On Render, the literal would write String.Format(this.FormatString,this.Value) to the output.  Pretty simple control, and it would allow you to still use your declarative style of assigning values.

Comment: I believe, the example should be                 
Blah.Text = string.Format(
    GetLocalResourceObject("Blah.Format").ToString(),paramCategory
);
where resource value for English will be "Enter the {0} category"